# Is there a way to enable Cors on Wso2 Identity server?

Tags: soap, wso2-identity-server

I have tried making a soap call to the AuthenticationAdmin API of the WSO2 Identity Server - https://"https://localhost:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin?wsdl

I am getting an error

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you please explain the way you tried to invoke the admin service. Did you created a API for this soap service or not. By default you do not require to enable CORS to access admin services. Here are some references.

[1] http://pradeepfernando.blogspot.com/2010/12/how-to-consume-admin-services-in-wso2.html
[2] http://nandikajayawardana.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-invoke-admin-services-with-soapui.html